# Get email details based on the dates in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am using the below mentioned apps script to get the email details in google sheets based on the label name updated in the particular cell.

```
    function getBaEmails() {
    var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = sheet.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
    var row     = 2;
    ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getMaxRows() - 1, 4).clearContent();
    var label   = ss.getRange("F1").getValue();
    var pattern = ss.getRange("F2").getValue();
    var threads = GmailApp.search("in:" + label);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
    var msg = messages[m].getBody();
    if (msg.search(pattern) !== -1) {
    ss.getRange(row,1).setValue(
    Utilities.formatDate(messages[m].getDate(),"GMT","MM-dd-yyyy"));
    ss.getRange(row,2).setValue(messages[m].getFrom());        
    ss.getRange(row,3).setValue(messages[m].getSubject());
    var id = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/"
    + messages[m].getId();
    ss.getRange(row,4).setFormula(
    '=hyperlink("' + id + '", "View")');
    row++;
       }
      }
     }
    };
```

I am trying to update the apps script which helps to get the email details based on the dates.

For example : I need a email details from `08/01/2019` to `08/30/2019`.

It would be great, if anyone help me to update the apps script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Gmail search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: How are those dates going to be fed in the script? Also via some spreadsheet cells? If that's the case, you can indeed easily reproduce the same steps as for your F1 and F2 cells, and use the content retrieved there in your `GmailApp.search()` operation using the operators linked by @Cooper above. On a side note, when writing content in cells, especially that are next to each other, best for performance to collect all the input in an array and do the `setValues()` operation once (or, alternatively, in your case, use `appendRow()`) instead of repeatedly for each cell.

Comment: Thank you so much @cooper and Benoit Wery. Is it possible to help me with example... When I tried to add before and after in GmailApp.search () it shows 3 strings not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

You can always test your queries in Gmail

```
function gmailSearch(label,after,before) {
  var label=label||'qs-vendors-google';
  var after=after||'2019/01/01';
  var before=before||'2019/08/01';
  var html='';
  var qry=Utilities.formatString('label:%s after:%s before:%s',label,after,before);
  var results=GmailApp.search(qry);
  for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
    var msgs=results[i].getMessages()
    for(j=0;j<msgs.length;j++) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<strong>Date:</strong> %s <strong>From: </strong> %s <strong>Subject: </strong> %s<br />',msgs[j].getDate(),msgs[j].getFrom(),msgs[j].getSubject());
    }
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Search Results')
}
```